# JS works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I can't figure out why this isn't working in FF? It does work in Chrome and Firebug doesn't show any errors in FF, but it's being ignored.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(function(){
                $('#content-left').css({'display': 'block !important', 'width': '80px !important'});
                $('#content-right').css('width', '250px !important');
                $('#content-middle').css({'width': '630px !important', 'float': 'left !important', 'height': 'auto !important', 'padding': '0 10px !important'});
            });

        });
```

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `!important` at inline styles at Firefox.

Besides, you shouldn't use `!important` *UNLESS* you've got no other options left.
In your case, `!important` is unnecessary, because inline styles already have a very high specificity.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob! That didn't even occur to me but seems so obvious now.

Comment: You can use `!important` just fine in inline styles in Firefox...  What you can't do is set `style.left.height = "250px !important"`, because the spec doesn't allow that, but if you use `setProperty` (which lets you specify the priority) it works just fine.